# $match aggregate in mongoose

Tags: http, mongoose

I am using $match to find a userid that is reference in my schema.  When I pass in http://localhost:3001/api/orders/5d6f1611d3bcd442bc273211/2018-02-01/2019-09-01 I get the following:

```
5d6f1611d3bcd442bc273211
[0] 2018-02-01
[0] 2019-09-01
[0] ReferenceError: $match is not defined
```

Here is my code:

```
getOrderTotal: function (req, res) {
    const userID = req.params.userid;
    const firstDate = req.params.firstdate;
    const secondDate = req.params.seconddate;
    console.log(userID);
    console.log(firstDate);
    console.log(secondDate);
    Order
      .aggregate([{ $match: { 'user': userID } }])
      .find({ "created_at": { "$gte": firstDate, "$lt": secondDate } })
      .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
  }
```

When I remove the line containing $match, I get the expected results. When I leave it in, I get an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

convert userId to ObjectID

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userID);
```

Then use id in your $match aggregation

or

```
.aggregate([{ $match: { 'user': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userID) } }])
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this while also using the find statement?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this is what you want to achieve

1. Find document that has user matching userId
2. and has date greater than or equal to firstDate and less than secondDate

If you insist on using the aggregate pipeline plus $match operator, you must then be aware of the following

**Note:**
The documents returned are plain javascript objects, not mongoose documents (since any shape of document can be returned). More info here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html

**Example:**

```
getOrderByDate: async (req, res) => {

        // Get the parameter data from req.params
        let { user, firstDate, secondDate } = req.params;

        // Convert the user data type to mongoose ObjectId
        user = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user);

        // Convert both firstDate and SecondDate to date
        firstDate = new Date(firstDate);
        firstDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

        secondDate = new Date(secondDate);
        secondDate.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);

        // See the output in your console if you will...

        console.log({ user, firstDate, secondDate });

        // Using async (you can still use promises if you will)
        try {
            const matchedDocuments = await OrderDocument.aggregate([{ $match: { user: user } }]);

            // Filter returned document
            const result = matchedDocuments.filter((docs) => {
                if (docs.created_at >= firstDate && docs.created_at < secondDate) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            res.status(200).json({ result });
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).json({ error, message: 'Something went wrong' });
        }

    }
```

Comment: I need to use both find and match

Comment: The documents returned are plain javascript objects, not mongoose documents (since any shape of document can be returned). You could use the Array filter function to filter matching date range if you insist on using the $match operator. see https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$find` and `$match` at one time using **[expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)**.

```
const userID = req.params.userid;
const firstDate = req.params.firstdate;
const secondDate = req.params.seconddate;
console.log(userID);
console.log(firstDate);
console.log(secondDate);
Order.find({
   "$expr": { 
       "$and": [
           { "$eq": ["$user", userID] },
           { "$gte": [{ "$created_at": firstDate  }]},
           { "$lt": [{ "$created_at": secondDate  }]}  
       ]
    }
}).exec((err , found)=>{

});
```